# Run timer in the background with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I am trying to get my application to have a count down timer run while the app is in the background or even dismissed. The way I am trying to implement this is have a 24 hour count down to when the user has to complete a task. I see that the stop watch app on the iPhone works even when terminated, how is this accomplished?

Comment: Have you [searched this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+timer+background)?